# PyMuPDF rect uncompatible with reportlab rect

Tags: python, coordinates, reportlab

i am trying to draw text blocks box which detect from fitz use reportlab

and here is what i tried:

```
doc = fitz.open("demo.pdf")

canvas = Canvas("demo_.pdf", bottomup = True)


def draw_auto_fit_text_block(canvas, x_1, y_1, text_block_width, text_block_height, font_name, font_size, text_content):

    text_block_frame = Frame(x_1, y_1, text_block_width, text_block_height, topPadding = 0, leftPadding = 0, rightPadding = 0, bottomPadding = 0, showBoundary = 1)
    text_block_styles = ParagraphStyle(name = "Normal", fontName = font_name, fontSize = font_size)
    text_block_content = text_content.replace('\n','<br />\n')

    text_block_story = [Paragraph(text_block_content, style = text_block_styles)]
    text_block_story_inframe = KeepInFrame(text_block_width, text_block_height, text_block_story)
    text_block_frame.addFromList([text_block_story_inframe], canvas)

for page in doc:

    page_width = page.rect.width
    page_height = page.rect.height

    print("[page width]", page_width)
    print("[page height]", page_height)

    canvas.setPageSize((page_width, page_height))


    blocks = page.get_text("blocks")
    
    for block in blocks:

        block_content = block[4].replace("\n", " ").replace("- ", "-").strip()

        block_x_0 = block[0]
        block_y_0 = block[1]
        block_x_1 = block[2]
        block_y_1 = block[3]

        block_width = block_x_1 - block_x_0
        block_height = block_y_1 - block_y_0
        
        block_y_0 = page_height - block_y_0
        block_y_1 = page_height - block_y_0


        draw_auto_fit_text_block(canvas, block_x_0, block_y_0, block_width, block_height, font_name = "NimbusRomNo9L-Regu", font_size = 9.0, text_content = block_content)

    canvas.showPage()

canvas.save()
```

with this code, i can not draw the text with right box coordinates.
Anyone can help.

this is what i got:
[image]

the original pdf is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one problem:

1. PyMuPDF geometry has (0, 0) at a page's top-left!
2. Not sure how reportlab works here, but this is an existing PDF page and **may** have non-isolated coordinate system settings, so you may insert something at unexpected places.

The minimum you should do is using `page.clean_contents()` (`fitz.Page method`). This cleans up any mess of that kind.
Also confirm where reportlab assumes point (0, 0) to be: top-left or bottom-left.

Just to confirm, that the problm is not in PyMuPDF. The following code snippet:

```py
In [20]: page=doc[0]
In [21]: for block in page.get_text("blocks"):
    ...:     page.draw_rect(block[:4], color=fitz.pdfcolor["red"])
    ...:
In [22]: doc.save("x.pdf")
```

Produces this:
[image]

So best try to replace y0, y1 delivered by PyMuPDF by `page.rect.height - y0` and y1 by `page.rect.height - y1` in each rectangle passed to reportlab.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. For now I have been set page.rect.height - y0 and y1 by page.rect.height - y1 to my code. if I set the canvas = Canvas("demo.pdf", bottomup = False) I can got the right rect with report lab frame, but the text can not matched the rect.